# 'children' is missing in props validation -not props.children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

'children' is missing in props validation
In the following code snippet, children a is not known

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react'
export const AuthContext = React.createContext()
const authReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'login':
      const token = action.payload
      localStorage.setItem('token',token)
      return {state:token}
    default:
      return state
  }
}
const AuthContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, '')
  return(
  <AuthContext.Provider value={{state, dispatch}}>
    {props.children}
  </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
export default AuthContextProvider
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the prop types as the error says, add it before `export default AuthContextProvider` install it with `npm i prop-types --save`

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

AuthContext.propTypes = {

children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,

}
```